# Function that return a pointer to a struct with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes

The prototype of my C function is:

```
typedef struct {
    int a; 
    int b;
} foo_t;

foo_t* foo(int a);
```

In Python I have to redefine my structure:

```
class Foo(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("a", c_int), ("b", c_int)]
```

My question is how do I properly cast my return value in `Foo`?

```
>>> dll.foo.restype = POINTER(Foo)
>>> ret = dll.foo(42);
>>> print ret
<dll.LP_Foo object at 0xffe7c98c>
>>> print ret.a
AttributeError: 'LP_Foo' object has no attribute 'a'
```

I have also tried `Foo` instead of `POINTER(Foo)`. With this I can access `Foo` members but the values are wrong.

From [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) I can read this:

> ctypes.POINTER(type)
>   This factory function creates and returns a new ctypes pointer type. Pointer types are cached an reused internally, so calling this function repeatedly is cheap. type must be a ctypes type

So type cannot be `Foo`. I probably have to find another way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From documentation:

> Pointer instances have a `contents` attribute which returns the object to which the pointer points

So try:

```
>>> print ret.contents.a
```

Be aware that the documentation states:

> Note that ctypes does not have OOR (original object return), it constructs a new, equivalent object each time you retrieve an attribute

Comment: Or just use pointer indexing, e.g. `foo = ret[0]`. There's no problem indexing or using the `contents` attribute "more [than] once". Just note that all of the `Foo` struct instances this creates will reference the same memory, and none of them 'owns' the memory (i.e. ctypes won't free it). The C library needs to export a function to free the memory.